# Granting read-write rights to my web application on VPS

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, zend-framework

Am currently testing a bulk CSV import functionality web application and I came across a error

> The given destination is not writeable

My application is zend based and uses the MVC structure

```
application
--uploads
library
--Zend
public
--index.php
```

What Ubuntu command do I exectute to safely grant the necessary rights to my uploads folder in my web application?

Answer (score 0):

Use your FTP client (FileZilla for example) to set the permissions on your uploads directory to write access.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to use `setfacl` to allow you and you're web server to have write permissions to that directory.